# WordPress SEO By Yoast Plugin is interfering with a custom function code - how to troubleshoot and fix it?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to optimize my page load on my WP site. I've copied a custom function (can't remember where I pulled it from) to optimize my pages.

Things that it can are the following:

- move javascript to footer
- put css links on header
- collapse white spaces
- removes html comments

The function serves it purpose well, but when I install and activate WordPress SEO plugin (**v2.2.1**), the custom function does not minify my html page anymore.

The custom code I'm talking about is this:

```
class WP_HTML_Compression
{
    // Settings
    protected $compress_css = true;
    protected $compress_js = true;
    protected $info_comment = true;
    protected $remove_comments = true;

    // Variables
    protected $html;
    public function __construct($html)
    {
     if (!empty($html))
     {
       $this->parseHTML($html);
     }
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
     return $this->html;
    }
    protected function bottomComment($raw, $compressed)
    {
     $raw = strlen($raw);
     $compressed = strlen($compressed);

     $savings = ($raw-$compressed) / $raw * 100;

     $savings = round($savings, 2);

     return '<!--HTML compressed, size saved '.$savings.'%. From '.$raw.' bytes, now '.$compressed.' bytes-->';
    }
    protected function minifyHTML($html)
    {
     $pattern = '/<(?<script>script).*?<\/script\s*>|<(?<style>style).*?<\/style\s*>|<!(?<comment>--).*?-->|<(?<tag>[\/\w.:-]*)(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^\'">]+)*>|(?<text>((<[^!\/\w.:-])?[^<]*)+)|/si';
     preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
     $overriding = false;
     $raw_tag = false;
     // Variable reused for output
     $html = '';
     foreach ($matches as $token)
     {
       $tag = (isset($token['tag'])) ? strtolower($token['tag']) : null;

       $content = $token[0];

       if (is_null($tag))
       {
         if ( !empty($token['script']) )
         {
           $strip = $this->compress_js;
         }
         else if ( !empty($token['style']) )
         {
           $strip = $this->compress_css;
         }
         else if ($content == '<!--wp-html-compression no compression-->')
         {
           $overriding = !$overriding;

           // Don't print the comment
           continue;
         }
         else if ($this->remove_comments)
         {
           if (!$overriding && $raw_tag != 'textarea')
           {
             // Remove any HTML comments, except MSIE conditional comments
             $content = preg_replace('/<!--(?!\s*(?:\[if [^\]]+]|<!|>))(?:(?!-->).)*-->/s', '', $content);
           }
         }
       }
       else
       {
         if ($tag == 'pre' || $tag == 'textarea')
         {
           $raw_tag = $tag;
         }
         else if ($tag == '/pre' || $tag == '/textarea')
         {
           $raw_tag = false;
         }
         else
         {
           if ($raw_tag || $overriding)
           {
             $strip = false;
           }
           else
           {
             $strip = true;

             // Remove any empty attributes, except:
             // action, alt, content, src
             $content = preg_replace('/(\s+)(\w++(?<!\baction|\balt|\bcontent|\bsrc)="")/', '$1', $content);

             // Remove any space before the end of self-closing XHTML tags
             // JavaScript excluded
             $content = str_replace(' />', '/>', $content);
           }
         }
       }

       if ($strip)
       {
         $content = $this->removeWhiteSpace($content);
       }

       $html .= $content;
     }

     return $html;
    }

    public function parseHTML($html)
    {
     $this->html = $this->minifyHTML($html);

     if ($this->info_comment)
     {
       $this->html .= "\n" . $this->bottomComment($html, $this->html);
     }
    }

    protected function removeWhiteSpace($str)
    {
     $str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
     $str = str_replace("\n",  '', $str);
     $str = str_replace("\r",  '', $str);

     while (stristr($str, '  '))
     {
       $str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str);
     }

     return $str;
    }
}

function wp_html_compression_finish($html)
{
    return new WP_HTML_Compression($html);
}

function wp_html_compression_start()
{
    ob_start('wp_html_compression_finish');
}
add_action('get_header', 'wp_html_compression_start');
```

Using this function in my function.php reduces my page size to almost 5%.

Comment: No offence but after 10 sec. googling it showed that your code is from [setuix.com](http://setuix.com/minify-javascript-html-wordpress-without-plugin/), did you ask Damian de Costa already also? He is the dev/auhtor of that function and they even help out on their forum. *Not meaning by that that nobody can/will help you here but just out of curiosity asking.*

Comment: There are caching plugins that will accomplish what you are trying to do plus a lot more. I would consider using one of those. Regarding the problem at hand, Yoast also attaches an output buffer to the `get_header` action. Output buffers are stackable so that *shouldn't* cause an issue, but I would still try using a higher or lower priority on your call to `add_action`.

Comment: @mtinsley < I plan to use mod_pagespeed so I resorted to use the code instead. Furthermore, I already have too many plugins that slows down my admin dashboard.

Answer (score -2):

We got it working by changing the hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wp_html_compression_start' );
```

Comment: Hi fjorge, welcome to WPSE and thanks for your answer. Could you expand a little more to help others understand why this works, and perhaps how you came to the solution? Btw please feel free to [take the site tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out [How do I write a good answer?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more.